# Sproutcore + handlebars + jquery-ui - how to make a datepicker from an input generated by handlebars

Tags: sproutcore

The problem is that the doc.ready fires before handlebar finish generating the inputs jquery ui needs to set the date picker on.

Is there a better event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some code that I used for jQuery Data Picker with my SC2 demo app ([Chililog](https://github.com/chililog/chililog-server))

```
App.MyField = App.TextBoxView.extend(App.CriteriaFieldDataMixin, {
    valueBinding: 'App.pageController.fromDate',
    name: 'fromDate',
    placeholder: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    disabledBinding: SC.Binding.from('App.pageController.isSearching').oneWay().bool(),

    /**
     * Attach date picker to text box
     */
    didInsertElement: function() {
      this._super();
      this.$().datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
    }
})
```

Use the `didInsertElement` event to attach the datepicker.  This event fires after the DOM element has been inserted.